# ... (or it has a valid, but untrusted signature)

Tags: iphone, build, trusted-vs-untrusted

iPhone 3GS:  builds and installs just fine
New ipod touch:  "This provisioning profile does not have a valid signature (or it has a valid, but untrusted signature)."

All the related posts say to start from scratch on provisioning, but it works on my iPhone and iPad just not the iPod touch.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out another developers profile was on the iPod touch.  Removing it did the trick.  I guess you can't have one device provisioned to two different people?  I thought you could.